# CSV export date format in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

When exporting a chart to CSV is there a way to configure the date to day month year (dd-mm-yyyy) format as it is difficult to convert the date in Excel for graphing?

Sample of export:

[image: Exported date format]

when using the sample code example from Earth Engine:

```
// Define a FeatureCollection: regions of the American West. var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([   ee.Feature(    // San Francisco.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.45, 37.74, -122.4, 37.8), {label: 'City'}),   ee.Feature(  // Tahoe National Forest.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-121, 39.4, -120.8, 39.8), {label: 'Forest'}),   ee.Feature(  // Black Rock Desert.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-119.15, 40.8, -119, 41), {label: 'Desert'}) ]);

// Load Landsat 8 brightness temperature data for 1 year. var temps2013 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_TOA')
    .filterDate('2012-12-25', '2013-12-25')
    .select('B11');

// Create a time series chart. var tempTimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    temps2013, regions, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'B11', 200, 'system:time_start', 'label')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Temperature over time in regions of the American West',
          vAxis: {title: 'Temperature (Kelvin)'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 4,
          series: {
            0: {color: 'FF0000'}, // urban
            1: {color: '00FF00'}, // forest
            2: {color: '0000FF'}  // desert }});

// Display. print(tempTimeSeries);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a additional date property formatted in theway you want it to each image in the image collection:

```
// add a propoerty with the time formatted
temps2013 = temps2013.map(function(image){
  return image.set('timeFormat', image.date().format('dd-MM-yyyy'))
})
```

Then use that property as x label in the chart:

```
// Create a time series chart. 
var tempTimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    temps2013, regions, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'B11', 200, 'timeFormat', 'label')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Temperature over time in regions of the American West',
          vAxis: {title: 'Temperature (Kelvin)'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 4,
          series: {
            0: {color: 'FF0000'}, // urban
            1: {color: '00FF00'}, // forest
            2: {color: '0000FF'}  // desert 
            }});
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9e1afe0519316918756d70a42863be81)

Comment: Thanks Kuik, I have managed to get the date coming across onto the CSV export properly. A side effect of this method means the date in the user interface chart is also changed, do you know if there is an override to set it a different format such as year only?

Comment: You can just directly export a CSV with Export.table.toDrive() if you're purely interested in exporting.